# Angular event emitter vs click listener

Tags: angular

I am learning angular through "Your First App" section on their website.

One thing I have a question about is the event emitter.

Parent Component (**product-list**):

```
<app-product-alerts
  [product]="product"
  (notify)="onNotify()">
</app-product-alerts>
```

The `onNotify()` method just brings up an alert

Child Component (**product-alerts**):

```
<p *ngIf="product.price > 700">
  <button (click)="notify.emit()">Notify Me</button>
</p>
```

Child Component ts:

```
...
export class ProductAlertsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product;
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter();

...

}
```

My question is, what is the point of using an emitter here? The child component only has one item, specifically a button.

Why can't we just do the following:

```
<app-product-alerts
  [product]="product"
  (click)="onNotify()">
</app-product-alerts>
```

What was the purpose of introducing an emitter here?

**Is it wrong to attach click listeners to child components?**

Answer (score 0):

EventEmitters are Subjects (you can take advantage of RxJS library), you can pass a boolean as a parameter to define if the communication will be synchronous or asynchronous by default it is synchronous. I defined the basic communication from child component to parent component using event binding.

> My question is, what is the point of using an emitter here? The child
>   component only has one item, specifically a button.

The point of using a emitter is the fact that you need to establish a child -> parent type of communication. Having in the child component 1 element it is not a big deal, because you might be defining certain type of custom behaviour other wise you can have that button in the parent and use click event, but the design of component in Angular follows Atomic Design pattern for Components, that is the reason why you try to split components as small as possible.

> Is it wrong to attach click listeners to child components?

The first question that need to be answer is what are you trying to accomplish with this listener. 
I would say you need to take a look on the basics type of communication between components in angular.

1. Passing the reference of one component to another
2. Communication through parent component
3. Communication through Service

As you get to understand how the angular components communication works, you will realize that the listeners might not be the best solution, and as you make sense of all the scenarios you will be able to use the best way of communication.

By the way the listeners are very helpful once you use it wisely.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your child component might be missing some syntax. Do you know the data type you will be emitting? For example, if it's a `string` then your child component needs to look like this:

```
export class ProductAlertsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product;
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter<string>();

...

}
```

This is a part of TypeScript, this is what we call a generic annotation.

The `notify` thing right here is an eventing object or an instance of what is called an `EventEmitter`. We can use it to trigger events that get sent back up to the parent component. Your `onNotify()` method should probably be included inside that `ProductAlertsComponent` class as it seems that's where you want to send some information from your child up to the parent.

```
export class ProductAlertsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product;
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onNotify() {
    
  }

}
```

So inside that `onNotify()` you will add this.notify.emit() and then inside of there you are going to put the information you want to communicate out.

```
  export class ProductAlertsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product;
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onNotify() {
    this.notify.emit();
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

By default in Angular you can't listen on click component, however you could add host listener

```
export class ProductAlertsComponent implements OnInit {

@HostListener("click") onClick(){
    console.log("User Click using Host Listener")
}
```

Event emitter's main purpose is to pass data from child component to parent component not just for events listener